# Google analytics upload file with cURL

Tags: php, curl, google-analytics

I am trying to upload a .csv file to google analytics through php. Unfortunately, the google analytics API doesn't provide a way to save the filename, so I am trying to upload the file with cURL instead. I am stuck badly, mainly because I don't know how to properly translate a cURL command into php code.

This is the cURL command that uploads the file successfully, meaning it does exactly what I want, found [here](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=791#c4) :

```
curl -X POST -F "upload=@YOURFILENAME.csv;type=application/octet-stream" "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/analytics/v3/management/accounts/XXXXXX/webproperties/UA-XXXXXX-1/customDataSources/CUSTOMDATASOURCEID/uploads?access_token=ya29.REPLACEWIHTYOURVALIDTOKEN" -v
```

I have tried to translate the above command into PHP code in the following ways, but I am doing something wrong, because an invalid file is getting uploaded (probably an empty file ?).

## Attempt 1:

```
    $parameters = [
        'upload' => '@/local/path/to/my/file/test2.csv;type=application/octet-stream',
    ];
    $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/analytics/v3/management/accounts/' .
        $account->code .
        '/webproperties/' .
        $property->code .
        '/customDataSources/' .
        $datasource->code .
        '/uploads?access_token=' .
        $this->client->getAccessToken()['access_token']
    ;
    $process = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, true);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $return = curl_exec($process);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($process, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($process);
    // Runs, but the upload is invalid.
```

## Attempt 2

```
// Same as above, except the $parameters set like this
$parameters = [
   'upload' => '@/local/path/to/my/file/test2.csv',
   'type' => 'application/octet-stream',
];
```

## Attempt 3

```
// Same as above, except the $parameters set like this
$cfile = new \CURLFile('/local/path/to/my/file/test2.csv','application/octet-stream','upload');
$parameters = [
    'upload' => $cfile,
    'type' => 'application/octet-stream',
];
```

I did many other attempts which I fail to even remember by now. I can't believe it's so hard to get it working when I already have the command that works and all I need is to translate it into code ... hope someone out there can help me, thanks a lot in advance !

**EDIT**

In short, what I need to do is translate the following curl command into php code:

```
curl -X POST -F "upload=@YOURFILENAME.csv;type=application/octet-stream" "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/analytics/v3/management/accounts/XXXXXX/webproperties/UA-XXXXXX-1/customDataSources/CUSTOMDATASOURCEID/uploads?access_token=ya29.REPLACEWIHTYOURVALIDTOKEN"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after 2 weeks I was still unable to find a solution, so I ended up using exec. Yes yes I know I know, bad practice etc etc, but I am sticking with it until I find a way to do it properly.

Anyway, in case someone is as desperate for a solution as me, this is what I ended up with

`$result = exec('curl -X POST -F "upload=@' . $fullPathToFile . ';type=application/octet-stream" "' . $url . '"', $output, $return_var);`